# Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook sudo not found and Chef-Solo “undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass”

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm trying to make a cookbook that has some dependencies, but it doesn't work

**/recipe**
`ls`

default.rb

**Recipe:**

```
include_recipe 'sudo::default'
include_recipe 'user'

def will_create_user?(username, user)
    return false if node['etc']['passwd'].key?(username)
    return true if user['action'] == 'create' || !user.key?('action')
    false
end

node['authorization']['sudo']['groups'].each do |group|
        group group
end


node['vms']['users'].each do |username, user| 
    send_notification = will_create_user? username, user 

    user_account username do
        comment user['comment'] if user['comment']
        ssh_keys user['ssh_keys'] 
        groups user['groups'] if user['groups'] 

        if send_notification
            notifies :run, "execute[reset_password_#{username}]", :delayed 
        end
    end

    execute "reset_password_#{username}" do
        command "passwd -d #{username} && chage -d 0 #{username}" 
        action :nothing 
    end

end
```

**Metadata.rb**

```
...
version '0.1.0'
chef_version '>= 14.0'

depends "sudo"
depends "user"
```

**Berksfile.lock**

```
DEPENDENCIES
  vms-users
    path: .
    metadata: true

GRAPH
  sudo (5.4.5)
  user (0.7.0)
  vms-users (0.1.0)
    sudo (>= 0.0.0)
    user (>= 0.0.0)
```

**Attributes/default.rb**

```
{
   "vms": { 
     "users": {
        'magrini' => {
                'comment' => 'Bruna Magrini',
                'groups' => ['sysadmin'],
            'ssh_keys' => ['chave ssh'],        
               },
        }
   } 
}
```

I'm executing using `chef-client --local-mode default.rb`

**Error:**  Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook sudo not found

```
Recipe `sudo::default` is not in the run_list, and cookbook 'sudo'
is not a dependency of any cookbook in the run_list.  To load this recipe,
first add a dependency on cookbook 'sudo' in the cookbook you're
including it from in that cookbook's metadata.


Running handlers:
[2019-12-19T20:42:12+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2019-12-19T20:42:12+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Infra Client failed. 0 resources updated in 01 seconds
[2019-12-19T20:42:12+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /home/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2019-12-19T20:42:12+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2019-12-19T20:42:12+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook sudo not found. If you're loading sudo from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have a feeling that you are confusing something, since the title of your question mentions `chef-solo` when you are really using `chef-zero` (`--local-mode`).

you should definitely favor chef-zero over chef-solo (but i won't get into the reasons why).

in both cases (using chef-zero or chef-solo), you will have to download all the cookbooks and make verify chef-client knows where are the [cookbooks located](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html#run-in-local-mode).

if you ase using chef-zero, here are some references:

> Local mode does not require a configuration file, instead it will look for a directory named `/cookbooks` and will set `chef_repo_path` to be just above that. (Local mode will honor the settings in a configuration file, if desired.) If the `client.rb` file is not found and no configuration file is specified, local mode will search for a `config.rb` file.

[`client.rb` settings](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client.html#settings):

> `chef_repo_path`: The path to the chef-repo containing cookbooks and other files, such as environments or data bags, when running Chef Infra Client in local mode.
>
> `cookbook_path`: The sub-directory for Chef Infra Client cookbooks. This value can be a string or an array of file system locations, processed in the specified order. The last cookbook is considered to override local modifications.

since i see that you are using berkshelf, you can use [vendor sub-command](https://docs.chef.io/berkshelf.html#berks-vendor) to download all the cookbooks dependencies and place them in the same directory. then, have a custom configuration for chef-client, that sets the value of `cookbook_path` to the same directory which you used in conjunction with `berks vendor`, and finally execute chef-client.

Comment: I thought that when I do "berks install" it downloads the cookbooks that I set like depedency. If it doesn't, why do I have to do "berks install"?

Comment: `berks install` does download the cookboks, but `berks vendor` does some other stuff. the main thing to note here, that you need to instruct chef where the cookbooks are located.

Comment: I see. I will try. But if I did "berks install", where are the cookbooks? And i thought that client.rb was created on a node after bootstrap, if doesnt, who do I created? (sorry, I'm very new)

Comment: @BrunaMagrini: you are confusing, there is difference between the client.rb on the chef node and the client.rb on the operator node (used to be called knife.rb). by default, berkshelf will download the cookboks to `~/.berkshelf/cookbooks/`. but you are asking too many questions other than your original question. please createa another question and if you find my answer helpful, please accept it :)